# I'm having trouble understanding what the 'fct_reorder2()' function does

Tags: r

I'm trying to understand what the `fct_reorder2()` does but the R documentation is not clear on this. Below is copied from help for this function:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~color,     ~a, ~b,
  "blue",      1,  2,
  "green",     6,  2,
  "purple",    3,  3,
  "red",       2,  3,
  "yellow",    5,  1
)
df$color <- factor(df$color)
#> Levels: blue green purple red yellow

fct_reorder(df$color, df$a, min)
#>Levels: blue red purple yellow green

fct_reorder2(df$color, df$a, df$b)
#> Levels: purple red blue green yellow
```

Can someone help me understand why `fct_reorder2()` sorts the data this way?

Comment: (2021-03-03) Note to self.  In help it says "sort them so that values of fun(.x, .y) are in ascending order".  The question left is: what fun() is it?  In this case, fun() should take 2 values and return 1 value.

Answer (score 3):

The example in the docs is poor, because there is only one row of data for each factor level.

What helped me was [a chapter of R4DS: tidyverse and beyond](https://bookdown.org/Maxine/r4ds/sorting.html#sorting-by-another-variable), which is based on an example in the original [R4DS](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html?q=reorder2#modifying-factor-order), which I reproduce below.

> `fct_reorder2()` reorders the factor by the y values associated with the largest x values. This makes the plot easier to read because the line colours line up with the legend.

```r
library(tidyverse)

by_age <- gss_cat %>%
  filter(!is.na(age)) %>%
  count(age, marital) %>%
  group_by(age) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n))

ggplot(by_age, aes(age, prop, colour = marital)) +
  geom_line(na.rm = TRUE)
```

[image]

```r
ggplot(by_age, aes(age, prop, colour = fct_reorder2(marital, age, prop))) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(colour = "marital")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you!  I also read the book "R4DS".  I will have to figure this out myself.

Comment: Even this explanation is unnecessarily convoluted. As I understand it,  `fct_reorder2` calculates the last y-value for each factor provided the x-values are sorted and it uses those y-values to reorder the available factors.

Comment: @r_31415 By all means post an answer that improves on this one. But did you notice that this answer says "`fct_reorder2()` reorders the factor by the y values associated with the largest x values"?

Comment: I certainly noticed that, which is the reason I started looking up a simpler description of `fct_reorder2`. It is the type of definition that makes sense only when you already know what it does, but for beginners, it is too terse to be useful. I won't post an answer as a simple comment is enough.

Answer (score 1):

The `fct_reorder2` is using the `.fun` as `last2`.  If we check the source code

```
last2
 function (.x, .y) 
 {
 .y[order(.x, na.last = FALSE)][length(.y)]
  }
```

and now using `last2`

```
last2(df$a, df$b)
#[1] 2

df$b[order(df$a, na.last = FALSE)][length(df$b)]
#[1] 2
```

---

Now, if we check the source code of `fct_reorder`, it is calling `lvls_reorder`, which calls `refactor`

```
s1 <- tapply(seq_along(df$a), df$color, function(i) last2(df$a[i], df$b[i]))
forcats:::refactor(df$color, levels(df$color)[order(s1, decreasing = TRUE)])
#[1] blue   green  purple red    yellow
#Levels: purple red blue green yellow
```

---

Code lineage

```
fct_reorder2
function (.f, .x, .y, .fun = last2, ..., .desc = TRUE) 
{
    f <- check_factor(.f)
    stopifnot(length(f) == length(.x), length(.x) == length(.y))
    ellipsis::check_dots_used()
    summary <- tapply(seq_along(.x), f, function(i) .fun(.x[i], 
        .y[i], ...))
    if (is.list(summary)) {
        stop("`fun` must return a single value per group", call. = FALSE)
    }
    lvls_reorder(.f, order(summary, decreasing = .desc))
}


 lvls_reorder
function (f, idx, ordered = NA) 
{
    f <- check_factor(f)
    if (!is.numeric(idx)) {
        stop("`idx` must be numeric", call. = FALSE)
    }
    if (!setequal(idx, lvls_seq(f)) || length(idx) != nlevels(f)) {
        stop("`idx` must contain one integer for each level of `f`", 
            call. = FALSE)
    }
    refactor(f, levels(f)[idx], ordered = ordered)
}
```

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer.  I am a true beginner.  Two questions: (1) How do you get the function source code? (2) I spent 3 hours tracing the code you gave me.  The hard part (for me) is this: in fct_reorder2, there is a "summary" that takes value from tapply(). This tapply() takes arguments (a) seq_along(df$a) (b) df$color and (c) last2(df$a, df$b), what does this do?  I ran it and get : 2 2 3 3 1, exactly the same as df$b.

Comment: @Steve You can type the name of the function on the console and type enter.  For some functions, you may need to use `forcats:::` before the function name.  `tapply` is a group by function. and `last2` is another function which is applied by subsetting the columns by index `[i]`

Comment: It does not make sense to me so far.  I cannot understand.

Comment: I have downvoted this answer because it doesn't explain what the function is for.  It only reveals the code that is executed.

Comment: @nacnudus That is fair.  I upvoted your answer

Answer (score 0):

I was also confused by this function and it toke me a lot of time to understand. Here below is my understanding. I hope it helps.

Imagine that you are trying to draw a line plot with multiple lines. The lines are distinguished by their colors. Allow me to use code from @nacnudus, for clarity.

```r
library(tidyverse)

by_age <- gss_cat %>%
  filter(!is.na(age)) %>%
  count(age, marital) %>%
  group_by(age) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

```r
# here we use a customized sequential palette 

my_palette = c("#7a0177", "#c51b8a", "#f768a1", "#fa9fb5", "#fcc5c0", "#feebe2")

scales::show_col(my_palette)
```

[my_palette](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJ65W.png)

```r
ggplot(by_age, aes(age, prop, colour = marital)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = my_pallete) + 
  geom_line(na.rm = TRUE)
```

[line plot without reorder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehGhb.png)

The color without reorder the marital variable looks messy. To make colors match the data, we generally hope the color is sequentially correspond to the value that on the rightest end of each line, which means the larger of the value at the rightest point, the darker the color.

So our next mission is to reorder the variable marital according to their vlaue that in the rightest point (i.e, the value of prop at each marital's largest age).

```r
new_order = by_age %>% 
  group_by(marital) %>% # for each marital
  arrange(age, prop) %>%  # group first by age, and then prop
  dplyr::filter(age == max(age)) %>%  # find the largest age in each marital
  ungroup() %>% 
  arrange(desc(prop)) %>%  # reorder the data by prop
  pull(marital) %>% # get the new order
  as.character() # convert the new order to general character

# Then we plot the reordered line plot

ggplot(by_age, aes(age, prop, colour = fct_relevel(marital, new_order))) + # now we reorder the marital by new orders
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = my_palette) +
  labs(colour = "marital")
```

[reordered line plot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42Yd5.png)

Now it's colors look pretty reasonable.

And it's EXACTLY what `fct_reorder2()` does for you.

```r
ggplot(by_age, aes(age, prop, colour = fct_reorder2(marital, age, prop))) + # now we use fct_reorder2 to reorder marital
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = my_palette) +
  labs(colour = "marital")
```

[reordered line plot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZHGY.png)

What it does is for each marital, first order the data by age, then by prop, and then pick the last prop value (In this case, there is only one value). The picked values are used to reorder the factor level (by default `.fun = last2()`). If you define `.fun = first2()`， the function will reorder marital by the prop vlaue at each marital's smallest age:

```r
ggplot(by_age, aes(age, prop, colour = fct_reorder2(marital, age, prop, .fun = first2))) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_color_manual(values = my_palette) +
  labs(colour = "marital")
```

[reordered line plot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IK2L7.png)

I hope it helps.