# How does `fct_reorder2` compute this result?

Tags: r, tidyverse, forcats

Despite consulting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65240402/im-having-trouble-understanding-what-the-fct-reorder2-function-does) thread, I struggle understanding the following output:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~color,     ~a, ~b,
  "blue",      1,  2,
  "green",     6,  2,
  "purple",    3,  3,
  "red",       2,  3,
  "yellow",    5,  1
)
```

Which gives:

```
> fct_reorder2(df$color, df$a, df$b, .fun = min, .desc = TRUE)
[1] blue   green  purple red    yellow
Levels: purple green red blue yellow
```

I know you are supposed to use `.fun` differently with `fct_reorder2`. The `min` function here computes the mininum across all provided values, which are here the values in both `df$a` and `df$b`. I still would not expect the result I got. Can someone explain, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the linked answer's is downvoted for looking at the source but you're asking for the how so I think it makes sense to actually look at what the code for `fct_reorder2` does.

```
# This is fine, just checking if it's a factor and assigning the value.
f <- check_factor(.f)
# Also fine, they're columns from a data.frame
stopifnot(length(f) == length(.x), length(.x) == length(.y))
# We're not using dots
ellipsis::check_dots_used()
```

With that out of the way we can use the subsequent code with original data:

```
summary <- tapply(seq_along(.x), f, function(i) .fun(.x[i], .y[i], ...))
# for us equivalent to
tapply(seq_along(df$a), df$color, function(i) {min(df$a[i], df$b[i])})
#   blue  green purple    red yellow 
#     1      2      3      2      1
```

This is in this case just the pairwise min of columns `df$a` and `df$b`
If you had multiple rows per color it would use the minimum value from any row or column of the factor level.

```
lvls_reorder(.f, order(summary, decreasing = .desc))
```

This just orders levels based on those values in descending order, so the color with the *biggest* pairwise minimum of columns a and b first.
In the case of ties we can see it's sorted lexicographically leading to the output we see.

| color | a | b | pmin | dense rank | descending order (Lexicographically sorted for ties) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| blue | 1 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| green | 6 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| purple | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 1 |
| red | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| yellow | 5 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 |

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~color,     ~a, ~b,
  "blue",      1,  2,
  "green",     6,  2,
  "purple",    3,  3,
  "red",       2,  3,
  "yellow",    5,  1
)

df %>% mutate(
  nr = 1:5,
  min = ifelse(a<=b, a, b)
) %>% arrange(desc(min), nr)
```

output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  color      a     b    nr   min
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 purple     3     3     3     3
2 green      6     2     2     2
3 red        2     3     4     2
4 blue       1     2     1     1
5 yellow     5     1     5     1
```

That should clear everything up.

Comment: This doesn't exactly do the same. put the yellow row first instead of last for example and `fct_reorder2` will still maintain the same order due to the lexicographic tie breaking, yours changes the output because it tie-breaks by order of appearance.